# Different views when viewing newest unanswered questions

Tags: discussion

I'm running Ubuntu as host and as guest, using VMWare.  I can see some questions in the host, but not in the guest, and sometimes vice-versa.  Shouldn't the views be the same regardless?

Comment: i suspect cacheing issues

Comment: Have you tried different web browsers? Have you tried using the reload button in your browser? If that fixes the problem, that would indicate that caching issues, as @aking1012 suggests, are quite likely.

Comment: Reload button was used, Firefox, and Chrome were used, and I can assure you its not a caching issue.  I have tried clearing history, and that didn't help.

Comment: Are you logged in on both machines? (Also, this seems really really obscure. :p)

Comment: Probabaly you changed the time zone in the vm

Comment: Yes I'm logged on to both, and the time zone is that same in both.  It doesn't happen all the time, it just happens sometimes, I just noticed it more yesterday.

Comment: Screenshot or it did not happen!

Comment: I'll have to duplicate it.